# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.BookList_jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

I wrote an jsp file to get my book list from an mysql server. Here's my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<%-- set Data Source --%>
<sql:setDataSource 
    var="test"
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
    user="root"
    password="123456"/>
<sql:query dataSource="${test}" var="category" sql="select * from category"/>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Book List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <c:forEach items="${category.rows}" var="row">
        <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="col">
            <tr>
                <td>${col.value}</td>
                <c:set var="column" value="${col.value}" />
                    <%
                    String col = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("column").toString();
                    String strQuery = "select * from bookstore where Category='" + col + "'";
                    pageContext.setAttribute("strQuery", strQuery); %> 
                    <sql:query var="Book" sql="${strQuery}" />
                    <c:forEach items="${Book.rows}" var="row1">
                        <c:forEach items="${row1}" var="col1">
                            <td>${col1.key}:</td><td>${col1.value}</td>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </c:forEach>                                        
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I compiled it, I got no error. I tried to run it on a Tomcat Server, I got this:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.BookList_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.BookList_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:131)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Sometimes, I also got this when I refreshed page for several times:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [70] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Hoàng\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\Web_Sample\org\apache\jsp\BookList_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

An error occurred at line: 21 in the jsp file: /BookList.jsp
The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
18: </head>
19: <body>
20:     <table>
21:     <c:forEach items="${category.rows}" var="row">
22:         <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="col">
23:             <tr>
24:                 <td>${col.value}</td>


An error occurred at line: 21 in the jsp file: /BookList.jsp
The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
18: </head>
19: <body>
20:     <table>
21:     <c:forEach items="${category.rows}" var="row">
22:         <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="col">
23:             <tr>
24:                 <td>${col.value}</td>


An error occurred at line: 22 in the jsp file: /BookList.jsp
The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
19: <body>
20:     <table>
21:     <c:forEach items="${category.rows}" var="row">
22:         <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="col">
23:             <tr>
24:                 <td>${col.value}</td>
25:                 <c:set var="column" value="${col.value}" />


An error occurred at line: 22 in the jsp file: /BookList.jsp
The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
19: <body>
20:     <table>
21:     <c:forEach items="${category.rows}" var="row">
22:         <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="col">
23:             <tr>
24:                 <td>${col.value}</td>
25:                 <c:set var="column" value="${col.value}" />


An error occurred at line: 25 in the jsp file: /BookList.jsp
The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
22:         <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="col">
23:             <tr>
24:                 <td>${col.value}</td>
25:                 <c:set var="column" value="${col.value}" />
26:                     <%
27:                     String col = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("column").toString();
28:                     String strQuery = "select * from bookstore where Category='" + col + "'";


An error occurred at line: 25 in the jsp file: /BookList.jsp
The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
22:         <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="col">
23:             <tr>
24:                 <td>${col.value}</td>
25:                 <c:set var="column" value="${col.value}" />
26:                     <%
27:                     String col = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("column").toString();
28:                     String strQuery = "select * from bookstore where Category='" + col + "'";


An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /BookList.jsp
The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
28:                     String strQuery = "select * from bookstore where Category='" + col + "'";
29:                     pageContext.setAttribute("strQuery", strQuery); %> 
30:                     <sql:query var="Book" sql="${strQuery}" />
31:                     <c:forEach items="${Book.rows}" var="row1">
32:                         <c:forEach items="${row1}" var="col1">
33:                             <td>${col1.key}:</td><td>${col1.value}</td>
34:                         </c:forEach>


An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /BookList.jsp
The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
28:                     String strQuery = "select * from bookstore where Category='" + col + "'";
29:                     pageContext.setAttribute("strQuery", strQuery); %> 
30:                     <sql:query var="Book" sql="${strQuery}" />
31:                     <c:forEach items="${Book.rows}" var="row1">
32:                         <c:forEach items="${row1}" var="col1">
33:                             <td>${col1.key}:</td><td>${col1.value}</td>
34:                         </c:forEach>


An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /BookList.jsp
The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
29:                     pageContext.setAttribute("strQuery", strQuery); %> 
30:                     <sql:query var="Book" sql="${strQuery}" />
31:                     <c:forEach items="${Book.rows}" var="row1">
32:                         <c:forEach items="${row1}" var="col1">
33:                             <td>${col1.key}:</td><td>${col1.value}</td>
34:                         </c:forEach>
35:                     </c:forEach>                                        


An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /BookList.jsp
The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
29:                     pageContext.setAttribute("strQuery", strQuery); %> 
30:                     <sql:query var="Book" sql="${strQuery}" />
31:                     <c:forEach items="${Book.rows}" var="row1">
32:                         <c:forEach items="${row1}" var="col1">
33:                             <td>${col1.key}:</td><td>${col1.value}</td>
34:                         </c:forEach>
35:                     </c:forEach>                                        


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I tried to add taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar, jstl-1.2.jar, jsp-api-2.0.jar but nothing changed. 
Could you please give me some advices? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you deploy your JSP?

Comment: I used a Tomcat Server to build and run it on a web page with this: http://localhost:8080/Web_Sample/BookList.jsp

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes needed to make it work. Try below code

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${category.rows}" var="row">
        <c:forEach items="${row}" var="col"> -> Change {rows} to {row}
            <tr>
                <td>${col.value}</td>
                <c:set var="column" value="${col.value}" />
                <%
                    String col = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("column").toString();
                    String strQuery = "select * from bookstore where Category='" + col + "'"; //Make sure you pass relevant value
                    pageContext.setAttribute("strQuery", strQuery); 
                %> 
                    <sql:query dataSource="${test}" var="Book" sql="${strQuery}" /> -> Add datasource
                    <c:forEach items="${Book.rows}" var="row1">
                        <c:forEach items="${row1}" var="col1">
                            <td>${col1.key}:</td><td>${col1.value}</td>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </c:forEach>                                        
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```